# Extracting characters from a string - Python

Tags: python, string, extract

I thought this would be a straight forward thing, but I can't seem to extract and display the characters from the string

```
UserID=str(raw_input("Please enter your user ID:"))
Length=len(UserID)
FirstLetter=(UserID)[0]
SecondLetter=(UserID)[1:2]
Numbers=(UserID) [3:4]

print("FirstLetter"+ " "+str(FirstLetter))
print("Second two Letters"+ " " +str(SecondLetter))
print("Last three digits"+ " "+str(Numbers))

if FirstLetter.islower() or SecondLetter.isupper() or Numbers!=int:
    print ("First Letter must be upper case\n Second two letters have to be in lower case\n Last three digits have to be integers ")

else:
    print("Thank you User ID Accepted")
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? `Numbers!=int`?

Comment: @PythonLearner You seem to be confused about which version of Python you are using. `raw_input` is a method in Python 2 but print only uses parentheses in Python 3... which version are you using?

Comment: What do you expect your program to do (e.g., what output do you expect) and what does it actually do (e.g., what output did you observe)?

Comment: Please use lower case names for variables. By convention, camel case with upper case beginning is reserved for class names. (The python interpreter doesn't care, but you confuse human readers of your code.)

Answer (score 1):

```
FirstLetter=(UserID)[0]
SecondLetter=(UserID)[1:3]
Numbers=(UserID) [3:6]
```

This will give you first character, next two and the last three.

Note that substring [a:b] means that index a is included and b is excluded.

Your other code is still confusing. Can't really say what you are trying to do.

Comment: If it was an answer you were looking for then mark it as the solution for the question.

Answer (score -1):

Try `type(int(Numbers))!=int` instead